# Why OpenSubKey() method returns null when I try to access to a registry key in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, printers, registrykey

I'm trying to make a script that returns the default printer of a list of remote pc, by reading the registry key Device under the path Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows.
The problem in my code seems to be in the method  OpenSubKey which returns null so the method GetValue fails.
The path of the registry key should be correct.

```
$Workstations=Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\mmarinari\Downloads\pclist2.csv -Header "PcName"

Remove-job *
foreach($workstation in $Workstations) {
    Out-File  -FilePath $logpath -InputObject $workstation.PcName -Append
    Write-Output $workstation.PcName
    $Reg=$null
    $remotereg=Get-Service -ComputerName $workstation.PcName -Name RemoteRegistry
    if($remotereg.Status -ne "Running"){
        Get-Service -ComputerName $workstation.PcName -Name RemoteRegistry | Set-Service -StartupType Manual -PassThru| Start-Service
        Write-Output "Service Started"
    }
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('CurrentUser', $workstation.PcName)
    If($Reg -eq $null){
        Write-Output "Reg is null"
    }
    else{
        
            $RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows")
            $DefaultPrinter = $RegKey.GetValue("Device")
            Write-Output $DefaultPrinter  
            $RegKey.Dispose()    
            
    }    
    $Reg.Dispose()
}
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\mmwa\Documents\ProgrammiVS\find_default_printer.ps1:28 char:13
+             $DefaultPrinter = $RegKey.GetValue("Device")
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

EDIT: I've added the Dispose method for Reg and RegKey and the $reg= $null instruction but that don't solve the problem, the error already occurs in the first iteration.

Comment: When `$reg` is being assigned, certain errors/exceptions won't update `$reg`. In other words, if `$workstation = 'pc1'` and `$reg` is successful, then `$reg` will be connected to `pc1`. If on the next iteration, `$workstation = 'pc2'` and `pc2` can't be reached, then `$reg` will still contain the contents of `pc1` registry key. You could try `$reg = $null` at the beginning of your loop or at the end of your `else` statement.

Comment: I would also recommend running `$regkey.Dispose()` and `$reg.Dispose()` when you are done with those objects for reach iteration. Otherwise, you let those connections hang around in memory where instability ensues.

Comment: Take note that you are trying to open `CurrentUser`. I might point out that `CurrentUser` does not mean "user that is logged on interactively on the remote machine." It literally means "current user" (i.e., the user that is running the code).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Bill_Stewart , so what is the correct hive to use in the  OpenRemoteBaseKey method for the registry path(Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows) of a remote pc?

Comment: The short answer is that there is none. If you need to read the `CurrentUser` hive for some other user, 99.9999% of the time the correct answer is simply "run your code as that user" (e.g., a GPO script).